# ScrollView doesn't scroll up to the top after going through some edittext boxes using the next button on soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-keypad

I'm showing a dialog using DialogFragment, the layout of this dialog is defined as a vertical LinearLayout in which there are some TextViews and EditTexts. This LinearLayout is placed inside a Scrollview. The layout is something like this (sorry, i cannot share the exact code due to company policies):

```
<ScrollView
    layout_width="700dp"
    layout_width="500dp"
    overScrollmode="never">
    <LinearLayout
    orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView/>
        <EditText
           inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView/>
        <EditText
           inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView/>
        <EditText
           inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView/>
        <EditText
           id="scrollupStopsHere"
           inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView/>
        <EditText
           inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView/>
        <EditText
           inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If I go to the last EditText using the next button in keyboard, and then try to scroll up, it scrolls only till the edittext with id: "scrollupStopsHere", not till the topmost view.
Also, when the keyboard is not open, I'm able to scroll through the entire layout correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this from you Xml

```
  overScrollmode="never"
```

Comment: already tried that. doesn't work. i think the problem here is, when the keyboard is open and i have moved down to one of the editexts which accepts text, then if i try to scroll up it stops where it is not supposed to take text as input (the one above "scrollupStopsHere: edittext take numbers as input).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line of code & you are all set to Scroll in your dialog. **You must have your layout inside a ScrollView.**

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```